# unable to setState within if statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, setstate

Trying to update the react state within if statement.

When snapshot returns true -> switch state from true to false.
When snapshot returns false -> switch state from false to true.

If i console.log(this.state.notification) above the if statement, everything is fine, when i log or want to edit inside the if statement i keep getting error:
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.notification')]

i tried to use bind but didn't work.

Help please!

```
state = {
    darkMode: true,
    notification: true
};


toggleNotification = async () => {

    console.log(this.state.notification);       // no error

    const currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + currentUserId + "/notification");

    ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      if(snapshot){
        this.setState({ notification: false })  // error
        console.log(this.state.notification);   // error
        console.log('First check')
      } else {
        this.setState({ notification: true })   // error
        console.log(this.state.notification);   // error
        console.log('Second check')
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

There are three issues here (perhaps four): :-)

1. `this` is not what you expect in the `then` callback. You'd solve that using the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), **but** see #2:
2. Don't use `then` on promises in an `async` function; use `await`.
3. The "Unhandled promise rejection" tells us that nothing is handling errors from your `toggleNotification` function. Remember that `async` functions return promises, and that one of the cardinal rules of promises is: Handle errors, or propagate the promise chain to something that will.

#1 above is superceded by #2. Here's how you implement #2 in that function:

```
toggleNotification = async () => {

    console.log(this.state.notification);

    const currentUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("users/" + currentUserId + "/notification");

    const snapshot = await ref.once("value"); // <=====
    if(snapshot){
        this.setState({ notification: false });
        console.log(this.state.notification);
        console.log('First check')
    } else {
        this.setState({ notification: true });
        console.log(this.state.notification);
        console.log('Second check')
    }
};
```

(#3 you do where you *call* `toggleNotification`.)

---

I notice you log `this.state.notification` after calling `setState` to update it. Remember that [state updates are **asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), your state won't be changed yet as of that `log` call. If you want to log the updated state, use the completion callback (the second argument to `setState`:

```
this.setState({notification: false}, () => {
    console.log(this.state);
});
```

(Of course, if you were intentionally logging the old value of `this.state.notification`, fair enough, though it might be better to do that before the `setState` call if that's your intention, as it's easy to misread otherwise.)

---

If you like, you can avoid the duplicated code in that `if`/`else`

```
const notification = !await ref.once("value");
// Notice -----------^
this.setState({notification}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.notification);
    console.log(notification ? 'Second check' : 'First check')
});
```